# Convert XML String To CSV?

Tags: xml, vb.net, csv

I have an XML string that comes back from a 3rd party routine.  I would like to be able to output this XML string into a .CSV file in my VB.NET program.  Can someone offer some advice on the best way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: If you want to convert XML to CSV there is not a single direct conversion as XML allows for more.  Not all lines need to be the same.  Can have mulit-value.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```vb
' First read your XML string in
Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Parse(xmlString)

' Create a string builder to hold the output CSV
Dim theOutput As New StringBuilder(1000)

' Loop through the nodes of the XML
For Each node As XElement In doc.Descendants("name of element you want to start at")
    For Each innerNode As XElement In node.Elements()
        theOutput.AppendFormat("{0},", innerNode.Attribute("data").Value)
    Next

    ' Remove trailing comma
    theOutput.Remove(theOutput.Length - 1, 1)
    theOutput.AppendLine()
Next

' Write output to file and do whatever you want the file here
File.WriteAllText("path to file.csv", theOutput.ToString())
```

Comment: Dim xmlString As String = "<a>One<b>Two</b><c>Three</c></a>"
            Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Parse(xmlString)
            Dim theOutput As New StringBuilder(1000)
            For Each node As XElement In doc.Descendants("a")
                For Each innerNode As XElement In node.Elements()
                    theOutput.AppendFormat("{0},", innerNode.Element("b").Value)
                Next
                theOutput.Remove(theOutput.Length - 1, 1)
                theOutput.AppendLine()
            Next